# Last 13 full months SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, sql-server-2014

I have a database with a date column that logs when a new "contact" is created. The contacts are generated when the call center receives a new call or e-mail.

What I want is for the where clause to capture the last 13 months of full data.

Examples:

- Today is 1/30/2015, if executed the query would return records from 12/1/2013 to 12/31/2014.
- Today is 2/06/2015, if executed the query would return records from 1/1/2014 to 1/31/2015.
- The query will include those dates falling on the first and last days of the month.

The code I have is as follows:

```
WHERE 
   dbo.ub_contact.contact_dt BETWEEN DATEADD(year, -1, (DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 1, -1) + 1)) 
                             AND DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()) - 1, -1)
```

Ran today (1/30/2015) this code seems to be returning 1/1/2014 - 12/31/2014.

I would appreciate any help toward getting this worked out.

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this dates:

```
SELECT EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm, -14, GETDATE())))
```

So you where clause would look like:

```
WHERE dbo.ub_contact.contact_dt BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm, -14, GETDATE()))) AND EOMONTH(DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()))
```